# "[CALayer release]: message sent to deallocated instance" in UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, release, android-mapview, calayer

I have a MapView in an UIViewController. When I try to load the view after its viewDidUnload it crashes with this message:

-[CALayer release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x29aea0

I think I do all the necessary things that I should do i the viewDidUnload:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {

    [super viewDidUnload];

    locationManager.delegate = nil;
    [locationManager release];
    locationManager = nil;

    mapView.delegate = nil;
    [mapView release];
    mapView = nil;
}
```

My MapView is in an UIView configured in a xib-file. My VC is never deallocated.

I have been googling around for a while now but I can't find the answer.

**Edit**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Sansation" size:28]];
    [label setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
    [label setShadowColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = labelView;
    [label release];
    [labelView release];

    UIBarButtonItem *checkInButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Checka In" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(checkIn)];
    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:checkInButton];
    [checkInButton release];

    UIBarButtonItem *clueListButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ledtrådar" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cluesDown)];
    [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:clueListButton];
    [clueListButton release];

    UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar]; 
    [bar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.06 green:0.58 blue:0.88 alpha:1]]; 
}
```

"labelView" and "label" are IBOutlets.

Comment: Are the locationManager and mapView actually really retained ? I imagine that they're just added as subviews without having been retained, and then `[super viewDidUnload];` might release them and your releasing would cause the crash.

Comment: locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; and @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;. Is this the right way? And if [super viewDidUnload] is releasing the objects I should get an exc_bad_access in the viewDidUnload? The error comes after viewDidAppear but before you can actually see the mapView (just the grid).

Comment: You don't necessarily get a bad access exception when accessing a deallocated object. You can also either get the *message sent to deallocated instance* error or *unrecognized selector* if a new object now lives at that memory location. But you now say that the message comes *after viewDidAppear*, so you should show us this method instead. The `viewDidUnload` method is called when the view controller is releasing its views (cleanup).

Comment: There is nothing written in the viewDidAppear-method. I just had a breakpoint there to see if it was called. I will edit my question and add the viewDidLoad-method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have neither allocated nor retained `label` and `labelView` in your `viewDidLoad` method you may not release them here (you are overreleasing them).

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the problem! I'm sorry for my noobyness - still learning :)

Comment: @Erik Nolander: You're welcome. Memory management is the single biggest issue when learning Objective-C, but once you've learned and understood the rules it's actually very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Because you did some unwanted releases, like the class method return value.  you can release all you retrain object in -(void)dealloc